# Excel VBA, static variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function that would simulate the alternator activation (to recharge a battery). In a few words, my function "Alt" regulates the activation of the alternator depending on the **State of Charge (SOC)** of the battery. It is **On** as soon as **SOC < 30** and remains so until **SOC > 40**. Therefore the alternator will be charing to battery up to 40%, after that it goes to the **Off** state again.

Here is my code so far:

```
Function SOC(PrevSoc As Double, Power As Double)
    Static Alt_State As Integer

    If PrevSoc >= 40 Then
        Alt_State = 0
    ElseIf PrevSoc <= 30 Then
        Alt_State = 1
    End If

    If Alt_State = 0 Then
        SOC = PrevSoc - ((350 - Power) / (12 * 360))
    ElseIf Alt_State = 1 Then
        SOC = PrevSoc - ((350 - (Power + 3500)) / (14 * 360))
    End If
End Function
```

Note that depending on the alternator's state I would have a specific equation which would or would not take into account the additional power input from the alternator.

Now my problem is that the behaviour is very strange and I observe an activation at 36% for example. In my opinion it is related static variable "alt state". Would there be another way to resolve this issue in excel? Any help would be very appreciated.

PS: I could upload an excel file if needed

PS2 (Edit): The variable "Power" represents power input coming from another source that would recharge the battery as well. While Power = 0, the battery discharges following a simple equation, therefore with a constant rate (case of alt_state = 0 and considering Power = 0).

Comment: You're not stating what you want Alt_State to be if the PrevSoc is between 30 and 40.

Comment: Apologies, missed the static reference. How is this function being called?

Comment: I simply write "=SOC(W15;T16*1000)" in the next column on my "Data worksheet". I also repeat or rather drag it up to the final cell to get the whole column. So: =SOC(W15;T16*1000), =SOC(W16;T17*1000) etc ...

Comment: OK. can you give me a sample of W and T columns where it's causing you an issue? Edit it into your question maybe?

Comment: in which cells (address) do you actually write the SOC function?